# Grab the last executed command from history as a string and store in variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

I'm trying to grab the last executed command, with options, and store it as a string to be written to a file. I've tried using `fc` but that can only give me the next to last command (for me anyways) and I've also tried `!!:p` which gives the right command when I type it but I can't seem to get it to work in the function itself. Can I accomplish this?

Here's what's going on. `arg` is what I want the string to be.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

foo(){
    read HISTNUMVAR < histnum.txt
    TEMPHNV=$(fc -l 0 | grep -o '^[0-9]*');
    if [ $TEMPHNV -ne $HISTNUMVAR ]; then
        arg=$(***last history command here***);
        ./write_arg_to_file.sh $arg;
    fi
    echo $TEMPHNV > histnum.txt;
}
```

The script does everything else I need it to do besides grab the right history command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get something to work. From a command line, use:

```
history 2 | sed 's/^ *[^ ]* *//' | cut -d$'\n' -f1
```

From inside the script use:

```
arg=$(history 1 | sed 's/^ *[^ ]* *//')
```

This successfully saves the command and any options as a string.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably a cleaner way, but you can get the previous command from history with

```
prev=$(fc -ln | tail -2 | head -1)
```

Comment: The cleaner way: `fc -ln -1` avoids the invocation of `head` and `tail`.  You may want to strip the leading tab and space too - reinstating a pipe.

Comment: I've tried  `fc -ln -1` and it only gets the second to most recent command

Comment: When using it as a standalone command it works but in the script it's one behind the most recent command. For example, if I enter ls and then pwd the output file will only have just got ls appended to it. Also, this omits any of the options included in the command which, ideally, I would also capture. @glenn jackman

Comment: Well, why are you trying to re-implement bash's history mechanism?

Comment: The motive has value but isn't something worth going through the trouble explaining. `fc -ln -1` was my first attempt and, from a command line, absolutely works but didn't quite work when used in the script. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable history expansion in your script, as it is disabled by default for non-interactive use. `set -H` should do the trick.

Untested, but I am guessing that `arg="!!"` will do the trick.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the set -H? Also, I tried arg="!!" and unfortunately it did not do the trick.